# Nested template list error

Tags: c++, templates

In header:

```
list< SKPair<VALUETYPE> > *values[256];
```

In implementation:

```
const list< SKPair<VALUETYPE> > *bucket = values[0];
typename list< SKPair<VALUETYPE> >::iterator it = bucket.begin();
```

The gcc compiler complains about the second line:

`error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘bucket’, which is of non-class type ‘const std::list<SKPair<int>, std::allocator<SKPair<int> > >*’`

(Here in `main` I create a test instance of my class where `VALUETYPE` is `int`.) Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the line that is causing the error?

Comment: @anthony-arnold `typename list< SKPair<VALUETYPE> >::iterator it = bucket.begin();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write:

```
typename list< SKPair<VALUETYPE> >::iterator it = bucket->begin();
```

The `->` is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

`bucket` is declared as a pointer, so you need a dereferencing operator to access its members:

```
auto it = bucket->begin();
```

Should do the trick if you have C++11's `auto` available.